# Как из полной даты выводить только часы, минуты и секунды?

Tags: javascript, дата, время

Есть время, написанное

> Tue Jul 04 2017 23:10:46 GMT+0300 (Беларусь (зима))

Но мне нужно чтобы я мог получить в переменную только эту часть "23:10:46".Подскажите, как это сделать?

P.s.: Эту дату я получаю из миллисекунд, возможно есть способ получить время не посредственно из них?

```js
var time = 1499199458;
var date = new Date(+time * 1000);
var h, m, s;
h = date.getHours();
m = date.getMinutes();
s = date.getSeconds();
var correct_date = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;

console.log(correct_date);
```

Поскольку время в таком виде мне нужно было только для вставки его в `Html` такой вариант вполне меня устраивает. Но если не сложно то подскажите, как сделать так что бы когда кол-во часов, минут или секунд меньше 10 я получал например 01:09:05, а не 1:9:5?

Comment: Покажите код, как вы получаете это время

Comment: Используйте moment.js для форматирования времени из UNIX time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Распарсить дату, получить из неё всё необходимое и отформатировать:

ВНИМАНИЕ: Если есть сразу дата, то конвертировать её в строку, а затем парсить НЕ надо!

```js
var s = "Tue Jul 04 2017 23:10:46 GMT+0300 (Беларусь (зима))"
console.log(s)

var d = new Date(s)
console.log(d+"")
console.log(d)

var res = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].map(function (x) {
  return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x
}).join(":")

console.log(res)
```

Обращаю внимание, что этот способ пересчитает часовой пояс в текущий:

[image: Скриншот с часовыми поясами]

Answer (score 3):

```js
Data = new Date();
Hour = Data.getHours();
Minutes = Data.getMinutes();
Seconds = Data.getSeconds();
document.write('Текущее время: '+Hour+':'+Minutes+':'+Seconds);
```

Comment: Взгляните пожалуйста на обновленный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения результата в формате 09:01:05

```
subbed = new Date();
hour = subbed.getHours().toString().length < 2 ? '0' + subbed.getHours() : subbed.getHours();
min = subbed.getMinutes().toString().length < 2 ? '0' + subbed.getMinutes() : subbed.getMinutes();
sec = subbed.getSeconds().toString().length < 2 ? '0' + subbed.getSeconds() : subbed.getSeconds();
correct_date = `${hour}:${min}:${sec}`;
```

Для получения результата в формате 9:1:5

```
subbed = new Date();
correct_date = `${subbed.getHours()}:${subbed.getMinutes()}:${subbed.getSeconds()}`;
```